# How to maintain `lite` and `pro` of a library in git?

Tags: c#, git, github, gitlab

I have two versions `lite` and `pro` for my library. The files can be overlapping, different and `pro`-only.

I would like to maintain them on git, maybe one on gitlab and the other on github or both on gitlab, as gitlab supports private repos (for my `pro`).

Is there convenient practices for this scenario? I quite do not like to do commit actions twice.

Comment: What language(s) are you using. Where supported conditional compilation with different build configurations is the usual solution.

Comment: @Richard c# for unity plugin

Comment: In case you didn't know: GitHub does also support private repos. That's how they make their money just as GitLab does.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use [`#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) to add blocks of code depending on pre-processor identifiers defined by the [project configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2017).

Ie. rather than just "Debug" and "Release" builds you have "Lite-Debug", "Lite-Release", "Pro-Debug", and "Pro-Release" (and in larger projects four can seem a small number of configurations)

[Partial functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/partial-method) can also help (allowing code to call code that may or not be present).

---

If you want the "lite" version to be open source and the full to be closed then you need a different approach. Either you maintain the two versions in parallel (which would make contribution to the lite version easier, but take care on licence implications of copy third party changes to your closed version).

Or use a processing tool to extract the lite version from the full version, with all maintenance being done on the full, closed source, version.

Comment: I do want the "lite" version to be open source and the full to be closed. `#if` would not be good as it will leak pro code in lite version. Partial function would be a good suggestion for splitting files. It seems in your answer that I cannot avoid maintaining two repos, sadly. :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use a single repo. 
1) Make two different branches in git, lite and pro. 
2) Also make another branch called dev-lite, and dev-pro. This will have the devs work-in-progress versions. 
3) Also tell all devs to fork the repo. (or make separate branch each for each developer if forking sounds hard)

Now, the devs will fork your repo and will submit the changes on the dev-lite and dev-pro, whichever branch they are working on. There should be an admin who merge this changes after some code review.

4) Configure a Jenkins build server in such a way that as soon as the dev-lite or dev-pro branch is updated by a commit, the build is run and published to their respective environments.

5) Now, comes the release stage, as soon as a decision is taken you need to tag a version in the dev-lite and dev-pro branch and rebase/merge your code to the pro and lite branches.

6) The code of this branch will be your production code and to be run live for the client.

In this way, you can put both the lite and pro in git in a single repo.